# Time track software

Tags: open-source, software-development, login, timer

I was wondering if there is a simple (open source)? time tracking platform that can handle this:

**Main Features**

- Web based
- Employees log in with their account, then check in
- Employees check out when they leave
- The employee describe what they used the day for
- Something clean and simple to use.

**Cool to have BUT not required**

- Some statistics (separate administrator access), like a table of all employees with the entire hours they spend in the company.
- Teams

The systems I have found on the internet are kinda huge and I don't need all of these details.

Comment: "describe" = just a textual description or a selection from a list or a tree of projects?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it's just plain text. Like diary or mini log.